# Error while reapplying Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to install the Service Pack 1 update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.. Although, it cannot locate the file 'DotfuscatorCE_5.0.2500.msi'
Does anyone know where I can find/download this file?

Erorr Message: "The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable." cont. "Click OK to try again, or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package 'DotfuscatorCE_5.0.2500.msi' in the box below."

Comment: Looks like the SP installer got corrupt during download. Try downloading again.